# Flip ONE axis of Quaternion ( from right to left handed coordinae system)

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix, transformation

There are a lot of similar questions, but I can't find the answer =(.
I get a quaternion from the sensor in right hand coordinate system. 
Then I draw an object in the Unity by this quaternion. Unity uses left handed cordinate system. 
And if I rotate sensor clockwise by one axis, one axis will always rotate in the opposite direction =(
I've read a lot of books, articles, forums posts for about 3 weeks. And I still can't find a solution.

I've tested follow algorithms:
1. Convert quaternion to matrix -> then convert matrix to left handed CS ( determinaте will be -1) -> and convert back to quaternion - this doesn't work.

Transformation matrix (3x3) = 
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 -1

Matrix in new CS = (Transformation matrix)*(q_mat)*(Transformation matrix)

2. Flip two component of quaternion also will save right CS. It will flip two axis.

And a lot of other methods....
Please help =(((

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert right-handed coordinate to Unity's left handed coordinate, use the function below:

```
private Quaternion rightCoordToUnityCord(Quaternion q)
{
    return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}
```

It came from Unity's [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html) and I've been using it since I found it. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: I did it, it' will swop X and Y and save right handed CS

Comment: Unfortunately no/ This method change rotation of two axis and now all three axis give rotation in opposite direction.

Comment: Are you sure? What's/Where is the input of the right-handed coordinate?

Comment: Yes. Without changes only Z axis give opposite direction. After return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w); All three axis has opposite direction.

Comment: Quternion from sensor in the right handed coordinate.

Comment: From accelerometer/gyro sensor?

Comment: It's complicated sensor, with acc, gyro, mag and MCU on board, and return data are quaternion of orientation in right handed CS.

Comment: This should work. I don't know why it's not working for you. Can you try `Quaternion.Inverse`? That should give you the left handed coords too,